# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Significance Formula

Tags: statistics

I am writing a MSc thesis on an algorithm that uses the two-sample KS test for evaluating equality of two CDFs based on "Nonparametric segmentation of nonstationary time series" by S. Camargo et all. My question is relative to interpreting and understanding formulas used in the calculation of the significance used in the book [Numerical Recipes in C](http://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf), starting at Ch 14.3 pg. 623.

My problems start with:
"The function that enters into calculation of the significance can be written as the following sum:

$$ Q_{KS} (\lambda) = 2 \sum _{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j-1} e^{-2j^2 \lambda ^2} $$

(...) In terms of this function, the significance level of an observed value of D (as a disproof of the null hypothesis that the distributions are the same) is given approximately by the formula

$$ \text{Probability} (D_{KS} > \text{observed}) = Q_{KS}\left(\left[\sqrt{N_e}+0.12+\frac{0.11}{\sqrt{N_e}}\right]\,D_{KS}\right) $$

(...) The nature of the approximation involved in [the above Eq] is that it becomes asymptotically accurate as the $N_e$ becomes large."

The book gives a routine to calculate the function $Q_{KS}$ that then enters in the KS test itself and I obtain

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch9Ha.png)

which I don't know how to interpret or even motivate. My supervisor said it's an important result to begin with.

The caption I have for it is:

*"KS probability function $Q_{KS}$ as a function of $\lambda$ in the limit of large sample sizes, $N \rightarrow \infty$.]{KS probability function $Q_{KS}$ as a function of $\lambda$ in the limit of large sample sizes, $N \rightarrow \infty$. When $N \rightarrow \infty$ the distribution of the weighted KS statistic, $D= D_{KS}\cdot\sqrt{N_e}$ is asymptotically the KS distribution with CDF given by $1-Q_{KS}$.  Plotted is the probability function $Q_{KS}$ given by Eq.~\ref{eq:qks} overlapped with three points that correspond to  $Q_{KS}$ values equal to 0.1, 0.01 and 0.05 versus the critical values for $\lambda$, $\lambda^c$, \cite{wikiKS} 1.22, 1.36 and 1.63, respectively, for the large $N_e$ limit, $N_e \rightarrow \infty$. These critical points fall perfectly onto the curve of the probability function $Q_{KS}$."*

Can anyone help me interpret this? Is my caption clear and correct? What does $Q_{KS}$ actually mean?

Comment: hm, what is the question?

Comment: @Math-fun I don't understand what information I can extract from the plot, its motivation and conclusion let's say. the formula says nothing to me, i don't understand the result. i'm sorry if its confusing and/or unclear and i totally understand if you want to insult me! this first result of my thesis i somehow just don't understand and the literature is very few and unclear. my academic training is physics so i don't really have a statistics background